# Getting issue on API call where I am returning response like Unauthorized

Tags: react-native, axios, amazon-cognito

I am trying to call an api using axios. The required params, headers I am passing correctly but on api hit I am returning response as api error: {"message":"Unauthorized"}. I tried with too many solutions like using bearer, jwt token, I also changed API calling library to fetch but still no success.

```
axiosGetWithHeaders('url',
      {
        param1: 'emailid'
      },{
        Authorization : 'token',
        ContentType: 'application/json',
      }

    ).then((res) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE", JSON.stringify(res))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('api error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        console.error('api error: ' + JSON.stringify(error.response.data));


      });
```

Comment: What kind of api? Can you post real sample with address.

Comment: This is aws cognito api

Comment: Look at https://medium.com/codefully-io/authentication-with-aws-cognito-react-and-express-b3acf17d37e6

Comment: I am not getting anything out from this link @Oleg. I used same params, headers in postman it's work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try with axios:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = accessToken;`enter code here`
```

Comment: Still no success with axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]. I tried yesterday. Still i checked it now but no success

Comment: Validate if you have valid token and 
Can you supply real sample with token for demo will be better  in codesandbox

Comment: How can i validate that. Because whatever i am printing in console same thing i used in Postman it works fine

Comment: You can generate Generate code snippets  for javascript in postman if it work:
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/ and validate your code with it.

Comment: Can you please create a chat and help me out. Or can you get access thr teamviwer

Comment: I generate that code snippet and used it in my code but still problem

Comment: send me  anydesk connection if you can

Comment: i didn't see chat option.

Comment: it'was  issue in params object of get  url